# Tags asoiaf and song-of-ice-and-fire

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a tag named [asoiaf](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asoiaf) witch seems to refer to the song of ice and fire. It is only used twice. I'm too low-ranking to do anything about it. I'd think, they are synonyms - but since it's only used twice it could be deleted too. So my question would be: Synonyms or deletion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags which aren’t attached to any question get [purged from the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags) by an automatic process:

> Tags which are misspelled should have the questions under them retagged to the appropriate tag, which will result in its destruction due to having no uses.

You can just remove them from the questions, and this process will take care of them.

If the tag recurs, then we can always make a synonym later; but in this case, it’s sufficient to let the system clean it up automatically.

Comment: Well asoiaf is not misspelled. It's just an abbreviation. But it seems the topic is moot since @SQB already took care of it ;-)

Answer (score 7):

I just made [asoif](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asoif) a synonym of [a-song-of-ice-and-fire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-song-of-ice-and-fire). This then prevents this from being an issue in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Just remove them from the questions. Unused tags are cleaned up automatically.

Comment: I see you already solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

We should have made them synonymous.

Here's why:

- A new user decides to ask several asoiaf questions and tags it as such
- They also add it to their favourite tags
- We delete them all over again
- New user is confused as that tag has vanished

It's similar to how duplicate questions are handled, we don't delete the question hoping no one else will ask something similar, we mark as a duplicate straight away.

Comment: That would have been my first choice too. But since the tag-system has an auto-complete function there is little use in abbreviations. I don't think new users will only by insecurity decide to tag his question asoiaf when auto-complete conveniently suggests a nicer tag. So this deletion is not the worst outcome.