# Tag synonym "ASOIAF" for "a-song-of-ice-and-fire"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Pureferret suggested this first on [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3625/tags-asoiaf-and-song-of-ice-and-fire/3628#3628), but it hasn't been made into a feature request, so here it is.

The [a-song-of-ice-and-fire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-song-of-ice-and-fire) tag should have the tag synonym [asoiaf](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asoiaf). It's easy, quick to type and a well-known shorthand for fans of the series. Pureferret listed other reasons in his answer, but I won't plagiarise them here.

Also, maybe a [got](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/got) synonym would be nice for [game-of-thrones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones).

Comment: I am bored to type `a-song-of-ice-and-fire` as well, so I just type `a-s` and it shows up :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bibbity-bobbity-boo.

All done!

Comment: Fab, thank you :).